# How can I have the LUIS authoring & prediction resource in different location

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I want to create my LUIS app in the UAE region. The authoring region is only available in three locations while the prediction resource location is available in UAE North. I created a prediction resource in the UAE North region using the Azure portal.

Now when I create an app in the luis.ai platform, I select the authoring resource which is created in `westus` location and I am unable to select the prediction resource which I have created in `UAE North` as it appears in disable state in the list.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your authoring resource to EU reigon

Comment: Tried creating the Authoring resource in the EU region, still the prediction resource in UAENorth is disabled in the list. @Maged Refaat

Comment: I communicated with the Product team, issue has been resolved and should reflect on your side shortly. UAE should be enabled under westus.

Comment: Hi @Maged Refaat, thanks for the update. I tried again in Azure Portal and found only 3 locations against the Authoring resource under the recommended list.

Locations are:
1. (Asia Pacific) Australia East
2. (Europe) West Europe
3. (US) West US

We want our both Authoring & Prediction resource in the UAENorth region which is currently not possible. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Hi @Maged Refaat, also the combination of having authoring resource in Europe region and prediction resource in UAE region is not available. Thanks in advance for your assistance. Looking forward.

Comment: Hi @MahaveerJain in reference to this documentation link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions
authoring is only available in three reigons Australia East, West Europe and West US. Prediction resource can be available in many other reigons as mentioned in the documentation.
In your case, (Prediction in UAENorth) you should have your authoring resource in West US.